# blueprint upload error in cloudify 3.3

Tags: cloudify

I have a written a very simple blueprint.yaml to install the MongoDB on a VM. When I am trying to upload the blueprint it gives me below error:

"An error occurred on the server: 400: Invalid blueprint - provider_context CONTEXT not found"

I am using following:
1. Cloudify CLI and Manager version: 3.3
2. It is successfully validated but issue comes while uploading blueprint.
3. I am using the embedded Nodecellar application blueprint

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: Cloudify version is: 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you will receive this error because you have a very large file in the same directory of the blueprint.

Please look for large files and move them from the blueprint directory or sub-directory's

Best,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed. Issue was with the manager bootstrap process.